# xode 6.4 iOS simulator layout not in sync with the Main.Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode6, ios-simulator

I am working on an iOS app in Xcode 6.4 . I am starting to develop the app and had the Main.storyboard a certain view. However, when I try to run the app in the iPhone simulator, the view is totally different and out of sync from the one present in the main storyboard. I am using the iPhone 6 plus simulator on Xcode 6.4 . Please see my attitude images to see whats it like on the storyboard, and how it changes in the simulator. Can you please let me know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project. Then your layout changes may apply. Or maybe you Auto Layout is broken.